# Tornado HTTPS questions

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, tornado

I'm looking to move my existing http server to use https. I know I have to first get an SSL certificate (underway).

Currently my implementation relies on a number of processes at the backend running on ports 8000, 8001, 8002, 8003

I have nginx on the front end that directs the http requests in a round robin manner to these ports. If I enable https on the backend ports I.e. 8000 - 8003 With :

```
HTTPServer(applicaton, ssl_options=ssl_ctx)
```

And i setup nginx with SSL options to listen on 443. Is that all i need to do.

I also have a nginx reverse proxy setup to deal with websocket connections to the same ports. Does moving to https change anything besides now having to connect with WSS instead of WS in javascript?

Do I ever need to establish any http connections? I want to move to purely https without any crossover with http. Is this normal and possible?

There are various other options listed in the tornado documentation:

> If xheaders is True, we support the X-Real-Ip/X-Forwarded-For and
>   X-Scheme/X-Forwarded-Proto headers, which override the remote IP and
>   URI scheme/protocol for all requests. These headers are useful when
>   running Tornado behind a reverse proxy or load balancer. The protocol
>   argument can also be set to https if Tornado is run behind an
>   SSL-decoding proxy that does not set one of the supported xheaders.

Can someone please explain what these do and if i need to worry about them?

Also when I type www.example.com into the webpage how does the browser know that it's a https and to connect to port 443 instead of port 80? Is this defined in the routing tables on the DNS for my site?